# $X\sim f(x)=K|x−1|,\;|x−1|<3$. Determine the correct limits.

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

\begin{equation}
X\sim f(x)=K|x−1|,\quad |x−1|<3.
\end{equation}
Determine the value of $K$.

Here, $|x-1|<3 \Longleftrightarrow -2 < x < 4$.

The question I have is, when getting the integral for $f(x)$, we have to take as two parts (since we have an absolute value)
\begin{equation}
\int_{-2}^0 f(x)dx  + \int_{0}^4 f(x)dx 
\end{equation}

or

\begin{equation}
\int_{-2}^1 f(x)dx  + \int_{1}^4 f(x)dx 
\end{equation}

**which limit part is the correct one and why? please advise.**

Comment: Since $f(x) =-K(x-1) $ for $x \le 1$ and $f(x) =K(x-1)$ for $x > 1$ it follows that $\begin{equation}
\int_{-2}^1 f(x)dx  + \int_{1}^4 f(x)dx 
\end{equation}$ is correct.

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you!

Comment: That one is the most appropriate indeed but in fact both are correct.

Comment: What does your "$X\sim$" stand for?

Comment: The distribution function of random variable X

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}\int_{-2}^4|x-1|\,\mathrm dx&=\int_{-3}^3|y|\,\mathrm dy\\&=2\int_0^3y\,\mathrm dy\\&=9\end{align}$$
hence $K=\frac19.$